# Delegated approver and record level access

Tags: sharing, approval-process, delegate

If a user A assigns a user B as a delegated approver, will this user B automatically get access to all records that user A has access to (the records owned by him or shared with him)? Or I have to set up sharing settings (using roles hierarchy, sharing rules, etc.) to provide this access?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. `Delegated Approver` allow the `user B` to know/receive the Emails from the `approval requests` or other `Email alert` which is sent from the SFDC org into `user A`.

But Technically, if `User B` need to do any action (Like update/approval) into `User A`'s records, **`User B` need to have the access for the records via `Profile` or `Permission Sets` for object level access and `Sharing Settings` or `Role Hierarchy` for record level access**.

Thanks.